# Remove Viewable data - Autodesk Forge Data Visualizations

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am working with the new Autodesk Forge Api Data Visualization and I would like to remove a single viewable from the model, once it has been created (Ex. create a UI to add and remove sensors in the model).

I found that DataVizualizationExtension has a method to remove all the viewables(dataVizExtn.removeAllViewables()), but I only want to remove a single one, so is there any way to achieve this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Currently the DataViz extension does not provide a method for removing individual viewables. I will pass your request to the engineering team but in the meantime, if you need to remove a specific viewable, you could achieve that with a bit of manual work. All the viewables exist in a viewer overlay (you can access the overlay manager via `viewer.overlays`) so if you find the right overlay scene, and the right `THREE.Mesh`, you can remove it yourself, kinda like so:

```js
const dataVizExt = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.DataVisualization');
const mesh = dataVizExt.pointMeshes[0]; /* somehow find the viewable mesh you need; here I'm just picking the first one */
viewer.overlays.removeMesh(mesh, "DataVizDots");
dataVizExt.pointMeshes = dataVizExt.pointMeshes.filter(m => m !== mesh); // Remove mesh from the viewables list
mesh.geometry.dispose();
mesh.material.dispose();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried what you said but it seems that all the viewable are on the same mesh. By now, I just remove all the viewable and create them again without the last I have removed, because it is enough fast.